# Remesh modifier creates unnecessary planes

Tags: subdivision-surface, displacement, artifacts, height-map

I'm trying to achieve a low-poly effect on an imported heightmap after applying Subdivision surface (Simple) modifier and of course Displace [image: first image]

but when i add a Remesh sharp i obtain this:[image: second]

Into which you can zoom in and see inside those four squary "islands" of the first image. So it's like it's creating some planes above when remeshing. I tried playing with the settings of Remesh aleready. Can anybody suggest me what to do? Thank you.

Comment: Is this a subdivided plane? If so, try to add Solidify before Remesh. Remesh works sketchy without volume